# Restoration from snapshots in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I am using virtual box and maintaining a regular back by taking snapshots and storing it in an external hard disk.Now the system in which my virtual box was installed have crashed. How can i recover my last work from the snapshots that have stored in the external hard disk.

Comment: its very urgent.someone please help soon.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what you mean by "taking snapshots" - VirtualBox supports taking snapshots but it sounds like you might just be copying the relevant XML and VHD files to another location?

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots are essentially "diff files" meaning that this file documents the changes between sessions (or within a session).

You can't diff a non existing base.

Example:

Lets look at the following set of commands:

- Pick a number
- Add 3
- Substract 4
- Multiply by 2

Now the outcome would change according to the first number you've picked so if the base is unknown the set of "diff" doesn't really help.

Try putting your hands on the vmdk/vhd/vdi file again, this might do the trick more easily.

Kind regards,
Yaron Shahrabani.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did is that you copy the snapshot to the default Snapshot folder of that vm e.g. for my Windows 2000 "Snapshot" folder is in /home/mian/VirtualBox VMs/Windows_Professional_2000_sp4_x86/Snapshots

Once copied run this command
vboxmanage snapshot Windows_professional_2000_sp4_x86 restore Snapshot5

If the name contain space e.g Snapshot 5 then run this command 
vboxmanage snapshot Windows_professional_2000_sp4_x86 restore Snapshot\ 5

It is for linux but you can almost similar for windows too like changing vboxmanage to vboxmanage.exe